# How can I implement a class template function with a std::enable_if metafunction?

Tags: c++, function, templates, implementation, enable-if

I have used the `std::enable_if` metafunction in my class template to specify that it is only allowed to generate classes for variables that have `GameCard` as a base class. This works fine on its own when I implement the functions inline. However, if I want to implement the template functions outside the header body I run into the issue that I can't figure out how to correctly specify the function that I want to implement.

Cut down example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct GameCard {};

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<GameCard, T>::value>>
struct CardStack {
  std::vector<T> cards;
  bool Test();
};
```

My IDE generates this as the function specification:

```
template<class T, class>
bool CardStack<T, <unnamed>>::Test() {
  return false;
}
```

This is obviously wrong since I'm getting compiler errors. But I don't have a clue on how to do it right. Do any of you know how to do this right?

Comment: `static_assert` seems more appropriate than SFINAE here.

Comment: Why do you think `static_assert` is more appropriate here?

Comment: Simpler syntax, and your SFINAE still produces hard error with invalid argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of class definition should be:

```
template<class T, class Enabler>
bool CardStack<T, Enabler>::Test() {
  return false;
}
```

But currently, you class might be hijacked:

Whereas `CardStack<int>` or `CardStack<int, void>` won't compile thanks to SFINAE,

`CardStack<int, char>` would be *"valid"* (risk to not compile because of hard error produced by `int` in `CardStack` implementation).

`static_assert` seems enough in your case:

```
template<class T>
struct CardStack {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<GameCard, T>::value);

  std::vector<T> cards;
  bool Test();
};
```

With simpler out of class definition:

```
template<class T>
bool CardStack<T>::Test() {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Judging by your good answer (and Biagio's good answer) I am now sure that I am ignorant on this topic; because this was not how I perceived things to work. However, I find it really hard to find decent information with examples. Are there any sources you would recommend on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

The function member definition should be something like:

```
template <class T, class U>
bool CardStack<T, U>::Test() {
    // body of function
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/us4TZv)

---

The explanation is pretty straightforward, there is no back magic here.
Just follow the normal syntactic rules of *C++*.

The definition of your class is a template class with two template parameters:

```
template<class, class>
struct CardStack { /* ... */ };
```

`T` is the name of the first one.
On the other hand, the second does not have any type-name, but only a default type (`= ...`).
Default type (similarly to default arguments for functions) does not have to be specified in the definition.

Therefore, the each method definition should be in the form:

```
template <class T, class U>
bool CardStack<T, U>::MethodName() {}
```

Comment: You're right. But I don't understand at all why you're right. Would you mind explaining this solution?